# Editing items in Swift / Realm

Tags: swift, realm

Trying to do a really simple todo app and I'm completly stuck with editing the existing items in the list.

This is the Item.swift file:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Item: Object {
    @objc dynamic var title: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var done: Bool = false
    @objc dynamic var dateCreated: Date?
    @objc dynamic var order: Int = 0
    var parentCategory = LinkingObjects(fromType: Category.self, property: "items")
}
```

the idea was to swipe left to get an edit and a delete button:

```
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
        -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

            let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete",
                                              handler: handleRowAction)

            let edit = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Edit",
                                            handler: handleRowAction)
            edit.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

            return [delete, edit]
    }

    func handleRowAction(action: UITableViewRowAction, indexPath: IndexPath){
        print("Action is \(action.title!) at Index Path \(indexPath)")

        let actionItem = action.title
        switch actionItem {

        case "Edit":
            print("Edit function")

            self.editModel(at: indexPath)

  case "Delete":
      print("Delete function")

      self.updateModel(at: indexPath)


        default:
            print("Default just in case")
        }

    }

    func updateModel(at indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // Update our data model
    }

    func editModel(at indexPath: IndexPath) {
        //Update our data model
    }
```

I had no problems with deleting items, but I can't really work out how to do the edit function. Currently when I tap the edit button, the text field pops up, it shows the current item, but when I type in the update and tap on the button, nothing happens obviously.

```
    override func editModel(at indexPath: IndexPath) {
        var textField = UITextField()

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Edit Item", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Edit Item", style: .default) { (action) in

            var updatedItem = self.todoItems?[indexPath.row].title
            updatedItem = textField.text!

            if self.selectedCategory?.items != nil {
                do {
                    try self.realm?.write {
                    //    realm?.add(updatedItem, update: true)
                    }
                } catch {
                    print("Error savig new items, \(error)")
                }
            }

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

    alert.addTextField { (alertTextField) in
        alertTextField.placeholder = self.todoItems?[indexPath.row].title
        textField = alertTextField

    }

    alert.addAction(action)
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

As you can see I tried

```
realm?.add(updatedItem, update: true)
```

but it gives me the following error msg: Cannot convert value of type 'String?' to expected argument type 'Object'.

How can I fix this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is on your line here:

```
updatedItem = textField.text!
```

You're setting that to a string. But Realm doesn't care about the string value. It wants the updated object itself.

Try replacing

```
var updatedItem = self.todoItems?[indexPath.row].title
updatedItem = textField.text!
```

with something like

```
var updatedItem = self.todoItems?[indexPath.row]
```

With that change, `updatedItem` is now the type Realm is looking for, and we now have a reference to our item that we can update safely in the write block.

```
try self.realm?.write {
    updatedItem.title = textField.text!
    self.realm?.add(updatedItem, update: true)
}
```

Also, beware that, because your model doesn't have a primary key, it may create a second object instead of updating the first.

Comment: yep, it asks for the primary key now. I guess that itself is a progress... how can I fix the primary key issue?

Comment: @Andras hold up a sec here. That won't work as you cannot modify a managed Realm object outside a write transaction. Additionally, if it is an existing object, inside the write you can just update the property directly - no need to use the primary key.

Comment: The hint there was.... add a [primary key](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#primary-keys) as you'll likely add it eventually anyway. `@objc dynamic var item_id = NSUUID().uuidString` and then the code from the docs is super simple and greatly helps organize, update and query your Realm objects

Comment: @Jay Thanks for catching the update outside of the write block. I haven't touched Realm in a while. I'll update my response.

Comment: Sure thing. Note that the UpdatePolicy changed a few versions back. It now accepts .error, .modified or .all rather than a boolean and .error is equivalent to false and .all is equivalent to true. [add(_:update:)](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Structs/Realm.html#/s:10RealmSwift0A0V3add_6updateyAA6ObjectC_AC12UpdatePolicyOtF) noting that it be .error for objects without a primary key. (hint, use primary keys!)

Comment: thank you guys, both of you! I noticed the outside-thing too, luckily it was easy to fix, thx for revisiting you answer tho. reading up on primary keys now, it seems like I will need to update my data models, but I guess thats gonna be another question for later!